# Write current page URL into anchor tag for microdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, document.write

I am trying to use jquery to write the current page's URL into an anchor tag, that I can then tag for schema.org microdata. Here's what I got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var url = document.URL;document.write(url);</script>
```

This writes the current page's url onto the page, however it is not in an anchor tag, and that tag does not include the proper microdata label of: `itemprop="url"`

Here is an example of the anchor tag I hope to achieve:

```
<a href="http://example.com/product" itemprop="url" />
```

I've tried searching around for a solution, but I simply do not know the programming language to accomplish this task. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks - Alex

Comment: You want just an HTML string which contains an `<a>` tag with the `href` set to `document.URL` and with `itemprop="url"` set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').append($("<a itemprop='url' />").attr('href',document.URL).text(document.URL));
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/kLu7j/

Or -

```
$('body').append($("<a/>",{
    href: document.URL,
    text: document.URL,
    itemprop:'url'
}));
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/kLu7j/1/

Comment: `.attr('href'),document.URL` typo? - anyway you can use jQuery's constructor directly, like this: `$("<a/>", {href: document.URL, text: document.URL})`

Comment: @LightStyle would you care to explain this method in an answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure pXL can do this for me - surely he knows what he wrote, and I don't want to get him his answer ;)

Comment: @AlexRitter  See this Demo with what LightStyle suggested  `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/kLu7j/1/

Comment: The script is working great guys! However - it would seem that either google is not running the script to get the data, or that the script is run to late for google to detect the data added by the script. Any thoughts on this?